# Listbox Onchange Event, component

Tags: delphi, components, tlistbox

I want to make a component based on `TListBox`.

When the `Items.Count` changes, I want to update the `Caption` of a `TLabel`:

```
Label1.Caption := IntToStr(ListBox1.Items.Count);
```

I made the component below, but it does not work:

```
unit UChangeListBox;

interface

uses
  Classes, StdCtrls, Messages;

type
  TChListBox = class(StdCtrls.TListBox)
  private
    FItemIndex: Integer;
    FOnChange: TNotifyEvent;
    procedure CNCommand(var AMessage: TWMCommand); message CN_COMMAND;
  protected
    procedure DoChange; virtual;
    procedure SetItemIndex(const Value: Integer); override;
  published
    property OnChange: TNotifyEvent read FOnChange write FOnChange;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure TChListBox.DoChange;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnChange) then
    FOnChange(Self);
end;

procedure TChListBox.CNCommand(var AMessage: TWMCommand);
begin
  inherited;
  if (AMessage.NotifyCode = LBN_SELCHANGE) and (FItemIndex <> ItemIndex) then
  begin
    FItemIndex := ItemIndex;
    DoChange;
  end;
end;

procedure TChListBox.SetItemIndex(const Value: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  if FItemIndex <> ItemIndex then
  begin
    FItemIndex := Value;
    DoChange;
  end;
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('MyComponents',[TChListBox]);
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TListBox` inherits a protected `Changed()` method from `TControl`, which sends a `CM_CHANGED` message to derived classes.  `TListBox` calls `Changed()` in reply to `LBN_SELCHANGE`.  You don't need to define your own `Change()` method, just handle `CM_CHANGED` instead.

`TListBox.SetItemIndex()` sends a `LB_SETCURSEL` message to the ListBox `HWND`.  That message does not trigger `LBN_SELCHANGE`, so you would have to detect the `ItemIndex` change yourself.  Which you attempted to do.

However, these issues only apply to **selection changes**, not to **`Item.Count` changes**.  Changing the `ItemIndex` does not change the `Items.Count`.  If your goal is simply to display a new `Items.Count` whenever an item is added or removed from the ListBox, you need to handle the `LB_ADDSTRING`, `LB_INSERTSTRING`, `LB_DELETESTRING` and `LB_RESETCONTENT` messages instead.

Try something more like this:

```
type
  TChListBox = class(TListBox)
  private
    FOnItemCountChange: TNotifyEvent;
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  published
    property OnItemCountChange: TNotifyEvent read FOnItemCountChange write FOnItemCountChange;
  end;

procedure TChListBox.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
var
  OldCount: Integer;
begin
  case Message.Msg of
    LB_ADDSTRING, LB_INSERTSTRING, LB_DELETESTRING:
    begin
      // for LB_(ADD|INSERT)STRING, Message.Result is the 0-based
      // index of the added string, or a LB_ERR... error code.
      //
      // for LB_DELETESTRING, Message.Result is the number of items
      // remaining in the list, or a LB_ERR... error code.
      //
      inherited;
      if (Message.Result >= 0) and Assigned(FOnItemCountChange) then
        FOnItemCountChange(Self);
    end;
    LB_RESETCONTENT:
    begin
      // the Message.Result is not used in this message.
      //
      OldCount := Items.Count;
      inherited;
      if (OldCount <> Items.Count) and Assigned(FOnItemCountChange) then
        FOnItemCountChange(Self);
    end;
  else
    inherited;
  end;
end;
```